# GRANDPA vs. BEEFY Light Clients

Tags: parity-bridges-common, bridge

I've been exploring `Substrate` development of `GRANDPA` and `BEEFY` light clients and I'm trying to understand their different uses and advantages.

**What are the unique features and advantages of each?**

In addition, I have a scenario I'm trying to understand better:

**Suppose I have two `solochains` using both `GRANDPA` and `BEEFY` finality gadgets. Would the `GRANDPA` light client be the better choice? If so, why?**

Any insights or resources would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Generally `BEEFY` was designed to use for efficient bridging with non substrate based chains mainly `ethereum` and it cannot work alone it is meant to be running alongside `GRANDPA` finality gadget for `substrate`. You can find more details about it here https://github.com/paritytech/grandpa-bridge-gadget/blob/master/docs/beefy.md.

A more detailed explanation of how `GRANDPA` and `BEEFY` is explained by parity team, you can find it here https://youtu.be/ZmIa_4hPRZ8.

A briefly explained answer by a fellow stack exchange member can be found here [What is beefy used for?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3632/what-is-beefy-used-for)

Answer (score 0):

GRANDPA and BEEFY are both finality gadgets used in Substrate-based blockchains to achieve consensus and provide finality guarantees. Here are the unique features and advantages of each:

GRANDPA (GHOST-based Recursive Ancestor Deriving Prefix Agreement):

Finality: GRANDPA offers fast finality, meaning that once a block is finalized, it is considered irrevocable and cannot be reverted.
Finality Gadget: GRANDPA is a finality gadget that provides finality guarantees through the use of voting and a recursive process to determine the finalized blocks.
Block Finalization: GRANDPA finalizes blocks based on votes from validators, ensuring Byzantine fault tolerance.
Security: GRANDPA provides strong security guarantees against various attacks, including long-range attacks.
BEEFY (Blind Assignment for Ethereum):

Light Client: BEEFY is a light client protocol that allows for cross-chain communication and verification of block headers and proofs.
Interoperability: BEEFY enables interoperability between Substrate-based chains and the Ethereum network, allowing for the transfer of assets and information between chains.
Trust Minimization: BEEFY minimizes the trust required between chains by verifying the correctness of block headers and proofs.
Simplified Security Model: BEEFY simplifies the security model by leveraging the security guarantees of the Ethereum network.

In the scenario where you have two solochains using both GRANDPA and BEEFY finality gadgets, it would be beneficial to use the GRANDPA light client. This is because GRANDPA provides fast finality and ensures Byzantine fault tolerance within the solochains themselves. The GRANDPA light client can validate the finality of blocks and ensure their correctness without relying on external chains like Ethereum. Using the GRANDPA light client would provide a more self-contained and secure solution for the solochains.